# Dynamic Folder path in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my .cshtml i am calling RenderXml as below which is a HtmlHelperExtensions Class
It takes 2 input, string xml and its path

> ```
>  @Html.RenderXml("","")
> ```

i am trying to use

> ```
>   ViewBag.myXML as string, Server.MapPath("") as two parameter.
> ```

If i want to pass the xml path during runtime [no hardcode] . How to do it?

i tried to use ViewBag but it is not allowing me to use here.

Please suggest me here.

Answer (score 0):

Created a class under Model with properties like Name and Age

Then in Controler, created a object of Model Class and assign the values and post that value to View.

in view
Refer the Model class

> ```
>  @using MyApplication.Models;
>   @model MyApplication.Models.ListClass;
> ```

and use list values as @Model.Name or @Model.Age